# How can I build a single jar for ehcache?

Tags: java, maven, jar, ehcache

Using echache 2.7.5, I tried

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package
```

but it makes many jars:

```
./terracotta/bootstrap/target/ehcache-terracotta-bootstrap-2.7.5.jar
./management-ehcache/target/management-ehcache-2.7.5.jar
./ehcache-core/target/ehcache-core-2.7.5.jar
./ehcache-core/target/classes/net/sf/ehcache/pool/sizeof/sizeof-agent.jar
./ehcache-scheduled-refresh/target/ehcache-scheduled-refresh-2.7.5.jar
./ehcache/target/ehcache-2.7.5.jar
./management-ehcache-impl/ehcache-rest-agent/target/ehcache-rest-agent-2.7.5.jar
./management-ehcache-impl/ehcache-rest-agent/target/original-ehcache-rest-agent-2.7.5.jar
./management-ehcache-impl/management-ehcache-impl/target/management-ehcache-impl-2.7.5.jar
```

and

```
./ehcache/target/ehcache-2.7.5.jar
```

doesn't contain any class files.

How do I target a single jar?

Comment: Do you want to build just one of those jars, or do you want all of them to be bundled into one "uber jar"?

Comment: The latter. My goal is to replace ehcache-2.7.5.jar that shipped with another project. In that project the ehcache-2.7.5.jar contained all the classes for ehcache.

Comment: Just throwing out some idea: isn't spring boot about creating "standalone" JARs for whatever purpose? Maybe their tooling could help you here.

Comment: I'm hoping to do this using the toolchain that exists in the ehcache repository.

Comment: Please indicate the java and maven versions used. Also what is the final output of your maven build? And finally how do you determine the jar is empty or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ehcache build uses a profile to build its shaded jar. The profile is named `fullmode` and needs to be activated: `-Pfullmode`.

The default is `devmode` which does not do the shading but instead produces pom files with proper transitive dependencies. The logic behind that is faster build times for devs who want to test changes of internal components and not have to rebuild the full jar each time.